# Haskell Parse Error inside do block

Tags: haskell, indentation

I'm getting the following error...

> parse error on input `args'

... while trying to compile the following code:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do 
    input <- readFile inputFile
    writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction   
    where mainWith function = do
        args <- getArgs  
        case args of
            [input,output] -> interactWith function input output 
            _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below 
        myFunction = id
```

The code is taken from chapter 4 of *Real World Haskell*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was indentation.  In the book I couldn't interpret the indentation correctly.
The code should be like this:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do 
    input <- readFile inputFile
    writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWith myFunction   
    where 
        mainWith function = do
            args <- getArgs  
            case args of
                [input,output] -> interactWith function input output 
                _ -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

        -- replace "id" with the name of our function below 
        myFunction = id
```

One of the bigger problems I'm having with learning Haskell are the vague compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

indentation in your question's code is correct.
You probably threw in a  in your code. There are many ways to force your editor to substitute every tab with 4 spaces.